# Empty area appears at the bottom of page on chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have problem on my website. If I open my website with HTTPS protocol, chrome shows an empty area at the bottom of page.

You can reproduce this if follows this steps:

1. Open new separate incognito tab using the lastest chrome version on windows
2. Go to [this page](https://xandaro.com). It will show a message that certificate is invalid. Ignore it.
3. At the bottom of page should appear unused area.

Why chrome shows this empty area on my page? It will disappear if I resize window. I also tried to disable all plugins, but it didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which version of Chrome that you are using, there is a reported issue of this grey area displaying only when the "Show bookmarks" (ctrl-shift B) is selected. Here is a link to the bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139765

The issue purports to be fixed in the current version of Chrome.